# Google Tag Manager custom javascript variable based on ecommerce datalayer object

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce, google-datalayer

I'm trying to calculate the value of the shopping cart based on data contianed in the GTM datalayer ecommerce object. I'm bringing the entire ecommerce object into a datalayer variable so I can work with it in the custom js variable, but I'm unable to make the recursive calculation work.

Here's an example of code from the datalayer:

```
{
  "event": "checkout",
  "ecommerce": {
    "checkout": {
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "coat",
          "id": "14M",
          "quantity": 1,
          "price": "100.00"
        },
        {
          "name": "pants",
          "id": "12L",
          "quantity": 3,
          "price": "50.00"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`
```

My goal is to identifies the number of products in the product array and then perform the calculation of products price * product quantity as many times as is required to go through the whol product array. In this case, it would be something like this:

(1*100) + (3*50) = 250.

I've tried modifying the code from [Simo Ahava's related blogpost](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/measure-cart-value-in-enhanced-ecommerce/) without success. The differences between his blogpost and my intention are:

1. I don't need to set the cart value as an ecommerce Custom Metric. I want to just return the value of the cart in the custom js.
2. I don't want this to involve adding or deleting items from the cart. Instead, I just want to calculate the value when the GTM Event "checkout" is triggered and calculate the value of the contained products.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have already created {{ecommerce}} variable , then it is very easy to fetch total amount on the basis of product's quantity and product's price.

You have to create on custom js variable **Order Subtotal**
then in that custom js box
paste below code

```
function(){
  var productList={{ecommerce}}.checkout.products;
  var totalAmount=0;
  for(var i=0;i<productList.length;i++)
  {
    totalAmount+=(productList[i].quantity)*(parseFloat(productList[i].price));
  }
  return totalAmount;
}
```

I hope this will help you resolve you issue

Comment: This was spot on, thanks Dinesh. I also modified this to also grab the product id's in a concatenated,comma-delimited list function(){
  var productList={{ecommerce}}.checkout.products;
  var productIds='';
  for(var i=0;i<productList.length;i++)
  {
    productIds = productIds + (productList[i].id) + ",";
  }
  return productIds;
}

Answer (score 1):

This JS function will take latest datalayer ecommerce event and calculate product sum:

```
function productSum() {
    var result = 0;
    var ecommerceDataLayers = dataLayer.filter(function(e){return e.event == "checkout";});
    if (ecommerceDataLayers.length)
    {
        var lastEcommerce = ecommerceDataLayers[ecommerceDataLayers.length-1];
        for(i=0;i<lastEcommerce.ecommerce.checkout.products.length;i++) {
            var product = lastEcommerce.ecommerce.checkout.products[i];
            result += product.quantity*parseFloat(product.price);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```