# Google Tag Manager custom javascript variable to calculate the total cart value

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to calculate the value of the shopping cart based on data contained in my websites datalayer.

```
​{
  event: 'checkout',
  ecommerce: {
    checkout: {
      actionField: {step: 1},
      products: [
        {
          name: 'Nude Fur Collar Quilted Puffer Jacket',
          id: 'Nude-JKT-6824',
          price: 39.99,
          quantity: 1,
          category: ['Clothing', 'Clothing/Jackets & Coats'],
          variant: [false, false]
        },
        {
          name: 'Black Side Stripe Knee Cut Jeans',
          id: 'JN-004',
          price: 19.99,
          quantity: 1,
          category: ['Clothing', 'Clothing/Jeans'],
          variant: [false, false]
        }
       ]
    }
  },
  gtm.uniqueEventId: 12
}
```

I have created a custom javascript variable with the following script, that i got from a previous question on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557541/google-tag-manager-custom-javascript-variable-based-on-ecommerce-datalayer-objec)

Dinesh's script works, but the output returns this number

```
59.980000000000004
```

I would like it to return this

```
59.98
```

Here is Dinesh's code

```
function(){
  var productList={{ecommerce}}.checkout.products;
  var totalAmount=0;
  for(var i=0;i<productList.length;i++)
  {
    totalAmount+=(productList[i].quantity)*(parseFloat(productList[i].price));
  }
  return totalAmount;
}
```

How can i modify this to output the result in the correct format, with two decimal places. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try using toFixed() method when returning the totalAmount. This method is useful in keeping a specified number of decimal.so using toFixed(2) would return only 2 decimal places.

```
function(){
var productList={{ecommerce}}.checkout.products;
var totalAmount=0;
for(var i=0;i<productList.length;i++)
{
totalAmount+=(productList[i].quantity)*(parseFloat(productList[i].price));
}
return totalAmount.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: try giving a detailed reply. like why this code matters? otherwise, it will be counted as Low-Quality Answer, even if it's right.