# Custom JS variable to count number of items in cart

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

My website pushes the following data to the data layer when a purchase is made

```
  ecommerce: {
    checkout: {
      actionField: {step: 3, revenue: null},
      products: [
        {
          name: 'Product 1',
          id: 4616,
          price: 516,
          brand: 'Brand Name',
          category: 'Product Type',
          variant: 'Product Version',
          quantity: 1,
          position: 1,
          dimension1: 'Guest',
          dimension2: '',
          dimension3: '',
          metric1: 2
        },
        {
          name: 'Product 2',
          id: 4618,
          price: 400,
          brand: 'Brand Name',
          category: 'Product Type',
          variant: 'Product Version',
          quantity: 1,
          position: 2,
          dimension1: 'Guest',
          dimension2: '',
          dimension3: '',
          metric1: 4
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I want to get the number of items in the basket as a variable in Tag Manager (i.e. 2 items in cart).
I'm trying to adjust [Dinesh's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807006/google-tag-manager-custom-javascript-variable-to-calculate-the-total-cart-value) solution from here that did something similar for total amount, but it's not working for me:

```
function(){
  var productList = ecommerce.checkout.products;
  var totalItems = 0;
  for(var i = 0;i<productList.length;i++)
  {
    totalItems+=(productList[i].quantity);
  }
  return totalItems;
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The code is correct, what does the `totalItems` returns? You need to check if `productList` has correct array data.

Comment: it returns an undefined

Comment: You need to check if the `productList` actually holds the array data.

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer, just find the length of the products which you are already doing in the for loop, that is the number of products in the basket.

Hope i answered your question